# Int not able to accomodate the result and hence program fails

Tags: java, algorithm

This is a leetcode problem number 2. I guess I am really dumb not able to solve this. I encountered a particular issue where I am not able to solve it for the test case

```
[9]
[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,1]
```

The issue is that my program is returning *1410065399* instead of *9999999991* when I try to make a digit out of the link list. I have mentioned the actual problem statement and my solution alongside. Please provide some light so that I can understand what went wrong.

**PROBLEM**
You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

**Example**

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

**Actual Code which I wrote**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
  }

class Solution {
    ListNode first;
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        int finalResult = returnNumber(l1)+returnNumber(l2);
        System.out.println(returnNumber(l1));
        System.out.println(returnNumber(l2));
        int length=0;
        if(finalResult!=0){
            length = (int)(Math.log10(finalResult)+1);
        }else{
            length =1;
        }
        for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
            generateList(finalResult,i);
        }
        return first;
    }

    public void generateList(int finalResult,int number){
        ListNode oldNode = first;
        first = new ListNode((finalResult / (int)Math.pow(10,number)) % 10);
        System.out.println((finalResult / (int)Math.pow(10,number)) % 10);
        first.next = oldNode;
    }

    public int returnNumber(ListNode list){
        int i=0;
        int base = 10;
        int total = 0;
        while(list!=null){
            total=total+(list.val*(int)Math.pow(10,i));
            i++;
            list = list.next;
        }
        return total;
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static int[] stringToIntegerArray(String input) {
        input = input.trim();
        input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);
        if (input.length() == 0) {
          return new int[0];
        }

        String[] parts = input.split(",");
        int[] output = new int[parts.length];
        for(int index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
            String part = parts[index].trim();
            output[index] = Integer.parseInt(part);
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static ListNode stringToListNode(String input) {
        // Generate array from the input
        int[] nodeValues = stringToIntegerArray(input);

        // Now convert that list into linked list
        ListNode dummyRoot = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode ptr = dummyRoot;
        for(int item : nodeValues) {
            ptr.next = new ListNode(item);
            ptr = ptr.next;
        }
        return dummyRoot.next;
    }

    public static String listNodeToString(ListNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return "[]";
        }

        String result = "";
        while (node != null) {
            result += Integer.toString(node.val) + ", ";
            node = node.next;
        }
        return "[" + result.substring(0, result.length() - 2) + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            ListNode l1 = stringToListNode(line);
            line = in.readLine();
            ListNode l2 = stringToListNode(line);

            ListNode ret = new Solution().addTwoNumbers(l1, l2);

            String out = listNodeToString(ret);

            System.out.print(out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the idea is to do the addition one digit at a time, carrying where necessary.  That should be work out better than converting each list to a numeric type, adding, then converting back.

Comment: I am doing that. If you can see the method gelerateLIst, you can find that I pull out the numbers based on their position on the number and then add them up. Hope I am not over complicating.

Comment: Yes, you are overcomplicating it.  If you were following the suggestion from my earlier comment, there would be no need to use the `Math.log10` or `Math.pow` methods; and no need to do any multiplication, division or modulus operations.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Ok let me try the alternate solution that you mentioned. Sometimes I feel like a real dumb.... :( Anyways Let me try it and come back.

Comment: Each element in the resulting list only depends on the values at the same position of the input lists and the accumulator.

Comment: The problem simply is overflow,`int` range is `2^31 - 1`, which is around `2*10^ 9`, while the number you need is `9*10^10`, just form a string or use BigInteger.

Comment: use `long` instead of `int`. e.g. `long x = 9999999991L`

Answer (score 0):

As the inputs are list instead of an Integer so there isn't a restriction on length of it. So I would suggest looping through the input and collecting the sum of elements as you go through it and creating the result list. (don't forget the carry which can be of multiple digits)

Below you can find my code for reference.
(Any suggestions will always be welcomed)

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode head = null, node = null;
    int carry = 0, sum = 0;
    while (!(l1 == null && l2 == null)) {
        // both not null
        if (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            sum = (l1.val + l2.val + carry) % 10;
            carry = (l1.val + l2.val + carry) / 10;
            l1 = l1.next;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        // l1==null
        else if (l1 == null && l2 != null) {
            sum = (l2.val + carry) % 10;
            carry = (l2.val + carry) / 10;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        // l2==null
        else if (l1 != null && l2 == null) {
            sum = (l1.val + carry) % 10;
            carry = (l1.val + carry) / 10;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        // both null
        else {
            // break out of the loop
        }
        if (head == null) {
            head = new ListNode(sum);
            node = head;
        } else {
            node.next = new ListNode(sum);
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
    if (carry > 0) {
        while (carry > 0) {
            int curr = carry % 10;
            node.next = new ListNode(curr);
            node = node.next;
            carry = carry / 10;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```